# Only update webdriver for one time and use it for various functions and loops

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, web-crawler

I have a simple web crawler, and I would use it in a loop to crawl information from youtube videos, as shown down below

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time

def Scrap(url):
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(6)

    #I will do some operations with the page source here

    driver.close()

urls = ["https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FWMIPukvdsQ", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ot4qdCs54ZE"]

for url in urls :
    Scrap(url)
```

Everything works fine, but it is annoying that I have to installed the driver twice. I think it has significantly slowed down the program when I crawl data from hundreds of websites. And it feels bad. I have tried two methods to only install the driver once and use it in various functions and loops.

Method 1: Manually assigned the path:

```
def update_driver():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

Then, the output will include the path of the installed driver, and I will manually copy and assign it to a variable so that other crawler functions can use.

Problem with Method 1:
I have to copy and paste it. Is there any way to automate it? Maybe I can gett the output of the installation and filter it?

Method 2:
Make driver a global variable.
Problem with Method 2: It would report errors when the driver is used for more than one url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem

- You are using the driver inside the `scrap` method which is making it to launch the browser as many times as your `len(URLs)`
- You closing the browser `driver.close` inside the `scrap` method which should be done after the loop.

The Solution

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())


def Scrap(url):
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(1)

    # I will do some operations with the page source here


urls = ["https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FWMIPukvdsQ", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ot4qdCs54ZE"]

for url in urls:
    Scrap(url)

driver.close()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It has solved the problem, but I have one more small stuff to ask. This is actually what I did in method 2, which has returned a connection error. The problem was that I closed the browser inside the function, so the program cannot make the connection with the second website. So now I delete the line of closing the browser and everything is fine. However, I am importing the Scrap function from crawler.py into main.py, and now I don't know where I should put the driver.quite(). If I put it at the end of crawler.py, connection errors will be reported.

Comment: Can you the show that you have implemented?